# Do I need Homebrew?

Tags: ruby, node.js, homebrew

I'm a .NET dev trying to get the hell out of MS and learn the other side.  That is the Mac OS and development...so please don't skip anything or make the assumnption that I know much here even after looking at the Home-brew site, etc.

If I'm not coding mobile apps using iOS or Swift, or I'm not coding Ruby (I'm coding all JS like Node, etc.) is [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) something I can still benefit from or do I not need it at all then?  What about XCode Utilities which installs the GCC compiler, do I still need those in a development environment that's going to be dealing with all JavaScript?

Homebrew is a package manager but if I'm using something like Node's npm, is Homebrew used for the same kind of deal but for Ruby?  I am kinda vague on all this.

Comment: Homebrew is for *any* apps; it's an app manager for OS X so you don't have to compile things manually. There are a ton of tools for the command line that aren't covered by `npm`.

Comment: I strongly recommend `homebrew` - the Apple stuff is quite out-of-date (`git`, `sed`,`awk`,`bash`) and `homebrew` keeps you up-to-date. `homebrew` is almost a requirement if you plan to use  `ImageMagick`.

Comment: By the way, to get the Apple Developer Tools (Xcode) just go to the AppStore and search for `XCode` and you can download them for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you are going to do purely Node.js development, there will come times when you need to install an npm module that contains a native C/C++ addon. When that happens, you will need to install the xCode developer tools (not sure if xCode itself is required...?).

xCode developer tools is an Apple-provided bundle of commandline stuff one usually needs to compile other stuff on Unix systems - make, configure, gcc, and a lot of other stuff which I know nothing about.

This alone should take you quite far. It might, in fact, be enough. However, there might again come times when you need to install an npm package that contains a native C/C++ addon that links against a shared library that is supposed to be installed on your system, but it is not (because Apple did not include it by default etc.) or, it requires a different (newer?) version of that library. And that would be the time when, instead of downloading and compiling the shared library yourself, you install Homebrew, type a command or two and voilá - the dependency is installed and ready.

Homebrew is a package manager for OS X as a whole, not just for a particular programming language. Usually (but not exclusively) it provides software that requires compilation (C/C++/Objective-C etc.). An example would be Node.js itself (so you can upgrade Node with a single command when there's an update), MariaDB, MongoDB, OpenSSL, OpenSSH, git, etc. Apple provides some of these, but they tend to get outdated very quickly - Homebrew helps you stay up to date.

Comment: you can upgrade node with npm, so not sure why Homebrew would be helpful if I can just do this: http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs

Comment: Upgrading Node.js is only one use case for Homebrew - surely at some point you will need to have some database - how will you install it? How will you keep it updated? You might do it manually, hunting each component update, or just do `brew update && brew upgrade` and go get a coffee.

Comment: also I see a lot of Ruby examples on the Homebrew site.  I don't use Ruby but yea I know now that Homebrew can be used for many things, not just Ruby.  And it's built over Ruby so you use ruby syntax?

Comment: thanks Robert, this is the kind of insight I need to save me pain.  I am totally new to this.

Comment: so would I be creating homebrew packages if I'm using npm?  Are homebrew packages used to create packages only for Ruby apps?

Comment: Homebrew is written in Ruby, but it provides a CLI to manage your libraries. And the libraries work similar to how npm works - there is a central repository with published packages from where Homebrew fetches either source (and compiles it for you) or a pre-built binaries.

Comment: So basically I do brew update and it'll go through all my npm packages and update them?

Comment: Homebrew has nothing to do with npm. :) npm is for Node packages, Homebrew is for system packages. The fact that they are both called "packages" is pure linguistics.:)

Comment: ok yea just trying to figure out what exactly Homebrew will provide for me outside npm.  Because when you say "it's a lot easier than doing everything by hand"...what's "everything'.  If I'm still installing individual packages with npm, and I'm using Express.js to generate a skeleton file structure for a website, what else is there to even worry about outside this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a whole lot of OS X without needing a third-party package manager such as Homebrew.  But the moment you find yourself installing software from third-party web sites, you should probably consider getting yourself organized.  The combination of [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and [Cask](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask) is useful for keeping track of what software you have installed and where it came from.  Plus, it's a lot easier than doing everything by hand.

Comment: Great for keeping track of updates too, and automatically installing them.